# How to deal with bad SDKs

Tags: c++, sdk

I have received a SDK to introduce in our framework. The SDK is used to interface with an oscilloscope and is provided by the manufacturer. I've read the "documentation", but its completely lacking.

Example:

```
DLL_API WORD WINAPI sdSetVoltageAndCoupling(
WORD DeviceIndex,
                                    WORD Ch1Voltage
                                    WORD Ch2Voltage,
                                    WORD Ch1_ACDC,
                                    WORD Ch2_ACDC,
                                    WORD TriggerSource)
Variables introduction:
DeviceIndex:    index of the device.
Ch1Voltage: index of the CH1 voltage
Ch2Voltage: Index of the CH2 voltage
Ch1_ACDC: index of the CH1 Coupling ( AC is 1, DC is 0, GND is 0 )
Ch2_ACDC: index of the CH2 Coupling
TriggerSource: index of the trigger source (CH1 trigger is 0, CH2 trigger is 1, ALT trigger is 2, EXT trigger is 3)
Note: 
This function is used for setting voltage and Coupling. If successful return 1, else return 0.
```

Nowhere in the documentation does it say what index is what voltage, and overall it has like no information at all.

How do you deal with SDKs you need to use, but are VERY poorly done? For example, the source code example, all the interesting stuff is in a file referenced by the solution, but the file itself is nowhere to be found, etc.

Comment: I usually search for other SDKs... or search Google to see if users had similar problems..

Comment: With other SDK, do you mean like going for a SDK implementing some standard (like IIDC1394 for cameras)? If so, this scope doesn't comply to any standards, and no other SDK can be used.

Comment: Create a usage-document that accompanies your project. you have to figure this out yourself (no help there unfortunately), but once you do, make SURE you document the hell out of what you discovered (and hopefully verified) so that readers of your code have an easier time understanding it than you did writing it (which should always be a goal anyway).

Comment: Try to get some code samples from the vendor, or take the advice fron devnull

Comment: You are yelling for help in a crowded football stadium.  The odds that you find the programmer that worked on this SDK here are miniscule.  Pick up the phone and give him a call.  If you can't get through then throw this away.

Comment: We can do next to noting to fix an underdocumented/broken SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's hard to understand, you'll need to learn more. Find other people using the same SDK (possibly here, maybe on the manufacturer's support site, etc) so you can ask questions. Contact the manufacturer directly. Experiment with each function individually.

If the SDK is just hard to use, write a wrapper for it that lets you use it at a higher level.

Answer (score 1):

First of all try to find as much information as you can. 
If you use oscilloscope, for example, try to find info about this model in the internet.
If there is no info about it, contact the producer.
As regards api, you can also contact with author, or finally experiment on your own.

P.S.
Be carefull with voltage ;).

good luck !